# Jar file not running when project and Renjin get compiled using a single Jar?

Tags: java, r, renjin

I'm making a java project on **Eclipse** that is using **Renjin.jar** file. The project run fine on IDE but when I export it to an executable jar file, it does not work or work partially until it reach a **Renjin.jar** part.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a self executing jar that includes all of the dependencies, then you will need a build tool like Gradle or Maven. Here is a blog post that walks you through it:

https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar